# Calculating slope of a quasar spectrum for power law fitting

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, astronomy

Working with Sloan Digital Sky Spectrum, I created a composite spectrum of quasars. The spectrum is a plot between wavelength (x-axis) measured in `Angstrom` and flux (y-axis) measured in `ergs/cm^2/s/Angstrom`.

For calculation of power law, I converted wavelength into frequency which resulted in `THz` scale frequency. On y-axis, I first changed the units from `ergs/cm^2/s/Angstrom` to `ergs/cm^2/s/Hz` by translating [this](http://hebe.as.utexas.edu/stools/pros/l2nu.pro) to MATLAB and than to `jansky` units. [This](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AkI0-ynaQIwJw1tb1wn3oYlTPP48) is the resultant plot.

Now I want to calculate slope of this graph, should I use the basic fitting tools and take the value of `m` from there? What are other methods to calculate slope for quasar spectrum for power law `f = f_o nu^(-slope)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `polyfit` with degree 1 to fit a linear model.

```
P = polyfit(Xtrain, Ytrain, 1);
```

P will be a vector of two components:

- The offset (or 0 degree component) and
- The slope (or first degree component).

You can then fit new data (test data) by applying the fitted linear model

```
Ytest = P(1) * Xtest + P(2);
```